# OpenERP 7 User Project Assignment

Tags: project, variable-assignment, odoo, settings

Fresh new Install  of OpenERP 7.0

I made a Very Simple Setup

admin
user1  (promoted permissions as far as possible in setup)
user2  (promoted permissions as far as possible in setup)

When I log in as admin
I can create a new project and assign any task (and maybe even the project) to either user

When I log in as either user1 or user2:
The user can create a new project but cannot assign it to their sibling.

---

### Mark as solved now

I have subsequently found that Assigning Portal to user1 or user2 breaks the ability to assign tasks in Project.  Portal requires locking down of rights which is underttandable but why this was the case was not obvious.  Similar results from SHARE and Multi-User.

Comment: Subject of allowing users to creat Projects seems to be a Bug in OpenERP 7.0.  This circles around "multi-user" and "portal" usage generally (toggling one or both modules off seems to fix some of these issues).  I however just solved this by going into the Postgres Database for res_companies and reassigning "user1" rather than "admin" be the user that is seen to have created the companies.  Unfortunately, I expect this is only a fix for "me".  It would be better to allow User1 to generally have the rights that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Less of an answer than a solution.  When USER 1 is checked in as having access to "Portal" the above situation occurs.

Previous, also discovered the same charachteristic when "SHARE" was selected.

Seems to be working now but the subject of OpenERP ACL and Rules is complicated.  Keep a log of any changes you might make (I didn't change anything but still)  Don't sign on for services you wont use.

Finally, if you have the ability to use "snapshots" for quick restores to working places during setups, worth throwing some you can use if you need.

Comment: AlanCham's answer is probably best.  The subjects of Multi User, Share, Portal, and Projects seem to trip over each other in OPENERP though fixes are in the works w/ new BZR builds.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt checked the "Portal" but still can not.

But after some testing, i found a solution:

1) first you create a Project and just select "Public" in Privacy. 
2) then save it.
3) then go Edit, and select "Followers Only" in Privacy.
4) and save again, it work,

and then you can used as your private Project, or add some follower.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem. Perhaps this is due to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1123940